# Get the previous link with HTTP Referer from a link with an anchor

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to get the link of the previous page with HTTP_REFERER to make a back button but this previous page has filter which update the url with an anchor.
For the moment I just get the simple url.

Thank you

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://website.com/cars/#blue-car/"):?>
     <a href="/cars/#blue-car/">
            <input type="button" class="back-button"></input>
            </a>
```

Comment: Have you tried `encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Don't know about this, I will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both of you, help me find the right solution.
I find this in an other post

Js

```
home_url = ['http://website.com/'];

pathArray = document.referrer.split( '/' );
protocol = pathArray[0];
host = pathArray[2];

url_before = protocol + '//' + host;

url_now = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;


function goBackOrGoHome(){
if ( url_before == url_now) {
window.history.back();    
}else{
window.location = home_url;
};
}
```

Html

```
<input value="Go Back" type="button" class="back-button" onclick="goBackOrGoHome()">
```

Comment: The post lost a part of my answer. Actually it compares the previous url and the actual one and it redirect to homepage if the previous url is from an  other domain.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be easily spoofed, I'd use `onclick="window.history.back();"`, i.e.:

```
<input value="Go Back" type="button" onclick="window.history.back()" class="back-button">
```

or `go(-1)`:

```
<input value="Go Back" type="button" onclick="window.history.go(-1)" class="back-button">
```

---

[Window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)